# How do I write a test over a background service that has Task.Yield?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, xunit

I have the following background service:

```
    public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            // Required for the method to be executed asynchronously, allowing startup to continue.
            await Task.Yield();
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                DoSomeWork();
            }
    }
```

However, I'm struggling to test this; I cannot await completion of `ExecuteAsync`, as the `Task.Yield()` just yields back to the current context. So in my test, `await service.ExecuteAsync(token)` returns immediately.

How can I test this without using a `Thread.Sleep` in the test?

Comment: Some test frameworks support async tests as well, which means you can await the async method you want to test, in your test code. Since you're using xUnit, make sure you're not using a really old version of xUnit and you should be good. And then basically you need to make your test method `async Task` as well and then await the call to ExecuteAsync and xUnit should take care of the rest.

Comment: Although `ExecuteAsync` returns immediately, if you're really awaiting the task *returned* by it, that await operation shouldn't return immediately - unless `stoppingToken` is canceled. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Quite arguable design. If you want to run some code on thread pool thread - why not just use `Task.Run` explicitly? Or in this case even better to create separate thread (or start task with `LongRunning` flag), because it seems you are doing some long operation, for which thread pool is not designed.

Comment: FYI, you can use _unconstrained_ mocking frameworks to substitute static and protected methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively hit the `ExecuteAsync` method by calling `await service.StartAsync(token)`.  As you say, you have an `await Task.Yield()` to address startup delays in the application; which will result in your `await service.StartAsync(token)` returning to you before your `ExecuteAsync` method completes.  To alleviate this in your test, follow the `await service.StartAsync(token)` with a call to `await service.ExecuteTask`

```
// Act
await service.StartAsync(token);
await service.ExecuteTask;

// Asserts are safe to perform now
```

Also note that the token passed to `StartAsync` is not the same as the token that your `ExecuteAsync` sees, so cancelling that token will not cancel your `ExecuteAsync`.  To achieve that behavior, call `service.StopAsync(default)`

Comment: this is the way!

Answer (score -1):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield#remarks):

> You can use await Task.Yield(); in an asynchronous method to force the method to complete asynchronously. If there is a current synchronization context (SynchronizationContext object), this will post the remainder of the method's execution back to that context. However, the context will decide how to prioritize this work relative to other work that may be pending. The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher than input and rendering work. For this reason, do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive. For more information, see the entry Useful Abstractions Enabled with ContinueWith in the Parallel Programming with .NET blog.

ASP.NET doesn't (by default) have a synchronization context, but `Task.Yield` might still be useful:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var t1 = DoSomethingLengthyWithYieldAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Before await t1");
    await t1;
    Console.WriteLine("After await t1");
    
    Console.WriteLine("----------");

    var t2 = DoSomethingLengthyWithoutYieldAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Before await t2");
    await t2;
    Console.WriteLine("After await t2");
}

async Task DoSomethingLengthyWithYieldAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before Task.Yield");
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("Before Thread.Sleep");
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Console.WriteLine("After Thread.Sleep");
}

async Task DoSomethingLengthyWithoutYieldAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before Thread.Sleep");
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Console.WriteLine("After Thread.Sleep");
}
```

With `Task.Yield`, you can get a `Task` from the asynchronous method invocation as soon as `await Task.Yield()` is reached.

To give more advice regarding your particular use case, we'd need to see the implementation of `DoSomeWork()`.

Answer (score -1):

> I cannot await completion of ExecuteAsync, as the Task.Yield() just yields back to the current context.

I assume you mean you cannot `await` the task returned by `StartAsync`, since `ExecuteAsync` is `protected`.

If you want to unit test your services like this, I recommend splitting your logic out to a separate testable type. `BackgroundService` "hides" the `ExecuteAsync` task as a private member.